# CSS relative change to inherit

Tags: css, inheritance, colors

Is it possible to do something like

```
color: inherit + #222;
```

So for example for  I want them to show off in a slightly brighter color than the rest of the text. Or do I have to write down every single html tag that could have a hyperlink ?

Comment: Use javascript and do it. If your element has an ID say "test", then do: ```test.style.color = your_color```

Comment: If you would do something like this with the background you could simply add a partially transparent background color to modify the background color of the parent. But with pure CSS I don't know of any way to achive what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use HSL colors and/or CSS variables.

More about [Color values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) and [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

Something like this.

```css
:root {
  --color: 0, 0%;
  --luminosity: 0%;
}

a {
  --luminosity: 50%;
  color: hsl(var(--color), var(--luminosity));
  /* 
    Or simply
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%)
  */
}
```

```html
<p>Yo i'm some random text, <a href="#">and I'm a stupid link</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In an ordinary CSS, this can not be done. If you use a SCSS,you can use special functions

darkest(#222, 10%)
lighten(#222, 10%)

Comment: so it would be color: lighten(inherit, 10%); ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The first parameter transmits the color, the second percentage by how much to increase or decrease the brightness. But as a color, you can pass a variable

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript to do the same:
If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in JS, do:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent')
var child = document.getElementById('child')
child.style.color = parent.style.color + '#yourNum'
```